# Removing whitespaces at the beginning of the string with Regex gives null Java

Tags: java, regex

I would like to get groups from a string that is loaded from txt file. This file looks something like this (notice the space at the beginning of file):

```
as431431af,87546,3214| 5a341fafaf,3365,54465      | 6adrT43   ,  5678  ,            5655
```

First part of string until first comma can be digits and letter, second part of string are only digits and third are also only digits. After | its all repeating.

First, I load txt file into string :`String readFile3 = readFromTxtFile("/resources/file.txt");`

Then I remove all whitespaces with regex :

```
String no_whitespace = readFile3.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

After that i try to get groups :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]*,\\d*,\\d*", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(ue_No_whitespace);
int lastMatchPos = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
    lastMatchPos = m.end();
}
if (lastMatchPos != ue_No_whitespace.length())
   System.out.println("Invalid string!");
```

Now I would like, for each group remove "," and add every value to its variable, but I am getting this groups : (notice this NULL)

```
nullas431431af,87546,3214
5a341fafaf,3365,54465
6adrT43,5678,5655
```

What am i doing wrong? Even when i physicaly remove space from the beginning of the txt file , same result occurs.
Is there any easier way to get groups in this string with regex and add each string part, before "," , to its variable?

Comment: You could use 3 capture groups after removing the whitespace chars `([a-zA-Z0-9]+),(\d+),(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/hrxr6A/1

Comment: @Abra that string i load from a txt file. It can contain a lot of this types of string (these values can occur like 1000 timex)

Comment: **Unable to reproduce**. When running that code with that text input, I get that output but without the `null`. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/gT2s8t) for proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split with `|` enclosed with optional whitespaces and then split the obtained items with `,` enclosed with optional whitespaces:

```java
String str = "as431431af,87546,3214| 5a341fafaf,3365,54465      | 6adrT43   ,  5678  ,            5655";
String[] items = str.split("\\s*\\|\\s*");
List<String[]> res = new ArrayList<>();
for(String i : items) {
    String[] parts = i.split("\\s*,\\s*");
    res.add(parts);
    System.out.println(parts[0] + " - " + parts[1] + " - " + parts[2]);
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/u5pBbn) printing

```
as431431af - 87546 - 3214
5a341fafaf - 3365 - 54465
6adrT43 - 5678 - 5655
```

The results are in the `res` list.

Note that

- `\s*` - matches zero or more whitespaces
- `\|` - matches a pipe char

Comment: I am not sure why, but this works. Maybe its some environment setup issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that you tried only has optional quantifiers `*` which could also match only comma's.

You also don't need `Pattern.MULTILINE` as there are no anchors in the pattern.

---

You can use 3 capture groups and use `+` as the quantifier to match at least 1 or more occurrence, and after each part either match a pipe `|` or assert the end of the string `$`

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)(?:\||$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/U1D27U/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/stGajw)

For example

```
String readFile3 = "as431431af,87546,3214| 5a341fafaf,3365,54465      | 6adrT43   ,  5678  ,            5655";
String no_whitespace = readFile3.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)(?:\\||$)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(no_whitespace);
while (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
}
```

Output

```
as431431af
87546
3214
--------------------------------
5a341fafaf
3365
54465
--------------------------------
6adrT43
5678
5655
--------------------------------
```